# Possible attack attempt on webserver, how to decode the requests to find out?

Tags: apache, webserver, xss, access-log

In my Apache access log I'm getting some requests like the following:

```
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x014\x8cO\v\x820\x18\xc6\xef\xc2\xbe\xc3{\xac\xc8\xa9\x87\x82\xf4$!\x19a\x04-:\xaf\xedU^X\xdbPQ\xf0\xd37\x0f]\x1e\xf8=\xff.\x95\x80\xa4\x95\x13)gy\x10\xa8\x85x$\x19\xcfXT*\x85~\xcca\x97\xec\xfe\x10WV9M\xb6\xcb\xa1[\xc8\xefAck\xe4\x88,:;kQ\x8d\xe4l\x0e7D\x1f\x97\x86\xa6\xe0\xd7n\b\x17\xf3<\xf3\x1e\xbd\x91" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\x9cS\xcbr\xda0\x14\xdd3\xc3?h\xd3N\x92F\xb6$\xcb/\x18O\x07l\xf3\b\x0f\xa7\xc14m7\x8c\xb0\x84qll\xc7\x98\xd0d\xfa\xf1\x15\x94\x94v\xdan\xba\xd2\xd5\xb9\xe7\xe8^]\x1d\xf5\xfd\x10\xa8\xab$\x13[5\xd9\xb0X.l\xa9\xae\x05\xe3\xa2\x82\\@\x96\xd5T)\xf3\x18\x0c\xc2\xf0V\xc5" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\xacU[o\xab8\x10~\xaf\xd4\xff\xc0K\xa5svORc \x81Vy\b\xd7$\x05\xa7\x10\x03\x81\x97" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\xacU[s\xaaH\x10~OU\xfe\x03/\xa9\xda\xcbQ\x87\x01T\x92\xf2A\xb9\xa9\x811 \x17\xe1%\x05\x0c*2 \x01\x94h\xe5\xc7\xef\xe0\x9e\x9cs\xf6\xec\xee\xcb\xd6\x96\x8e6\xdd_\xf7\xf4|\xdd\xf4h\x8a\xcd\x0c\xd2\"&'\x9c\xd4\x834\x0fw\xf4\xaf\xc2\x83\xa8)^\xeb\xb2J\x9b\x84\x1b\xf6\xcbb\xc7\xccm\xfbe\xc0\xf6\xd9\xfb\xbbi\x1c'e\xf3\xc8\xdc\xc0\x03j\xfb\xf2U\xac\xcf\xbb\xdf\xdfs\xf2\xf9\xf8\xdb\xd3\xdb\x04\xf4\xc7_\x98\xdf\x06\x7f\x8a\xc2\xa7oO)\xe2#N\x8b\xdd#\xb3\xbb\xa6\xe5\x17\x06'[\x126\xc97\xbb\x1e\x16\xbb\x13M\xe5\x91Z\xee\xef\xa4cQ$q\x93\x1e\x8bG\xe69I\xca\xde\x94\xa4\xe7\x9b\xfe\x98\xa5\x14#\xa9\vy\xb2\x8d\xd8-`y\xb6\x07\x841\xdf\xe3G\xf1\xb67\x1ec\xbe'\x80XH`\x84\x87\xe1\x88}\xa2P{\xf5\xac\xa0\txbdE\x9d:\xba\xad\xaf\xa4\xa9\xaeLp\xf2*+O\x8cah\xaf\xcf\x9eL\xe3\xb1\xfc\x10r=E\xe4\xa6\xcah6\xec\xc1\x99<\xec\xf1\xea\x90\xef\x89,\x90z\xb3!7\x94\x86" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\xacU[s\xaaH\x10~OU\xfe\x03/\xbbu\xf6\xecQ\x87\x01T\x92\xb2\xb6\x94\x9b\x1a\x18\x03r\x11^,`P\x91\x01\x89\xa2\xa8\x95\x1f\xbf\x83\x9b\xe4\\\xf7ek\x1f\xa6h\xba\xbf\x9e\xe9\xf9\xba\xe1\xd3\x14\x9b\xe9\xacR\x92\x1c:i\x1e\xae\xe9#\xc4\xa7e\x1a\xef\x96U\x9a'\xed\xb2X3c\xdb~\xee\xb0m\xf6\xfen\x18\xc7IY=07d\x87\xc6\xbe\xbc\x99\x87\xd3\xfa\xcfsN\xde_??\xbe\x0c@\xbb\xff\x85\xf9\xdc\xf9\xc7\x14\xdes[J\x11\xefpZ\xac\x1f\x98\xf55-\xbf08Y\x91\xb0J>\xe2zX\xac\x8f\xb4\x8e\x07\x1a\xb9\xbf\x93vE\x91\xc4U\xba+\x1e\x98\xa7$)[C\x92\x9en\xfe]\x96R\x8c\xa4N\xe4\xc1*bW\x80\xe5\xd9\x16\x10\xfa|\x8b\xef\xc5\xabV\xbf\x8f\xf9\x96" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\xacUko\xabH\x12\xfd\x1e)\xff\x81/\xbb\x9a\x19\rv\xf3\xb2\x8d#ke\xf3\xb2\x1dh\x07\xcc\xc3\xf0%\x02\xbam0\xcd#\x18\xc7\xb1\x95\x1f\xbf\x8d'\xf7\xde\x99;+\xad\xb4Z\xa1\x96\x9a\xaaS\xd5\xd5\xa7" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01\xacV[s\xaa\xc8\x16~OU\xfe\x03/\xa9\x9a\x99\xb3\xd5\xa6\x01\x95\xa4|Pnj\xa0\r\xc8ExI\x01\x8d\x8a4\x97 J\xb4\xf2\xe3O\xe3\xce\xde\x99\xd93\xf3r\xea\x94\x82\x8b^_\xaf^\xfd}\x8b\xd5j\x8a\xcd\x0c\xd2\"&'\x9c\x1c\x07i\x1e\xee\xe8O\x8d\x07QS\xbc\x1e\x93\xb0\x8e\xf7=\x92l\x9b~U\xec\x98\xb9m\xbf\x0c\xd8>{\x7f7\x8d\xe3\xa4j\x1e\x99\x1b~@}\xdf>\xcd\xe3y\xf7\x9f\xf7\x9c\xfcx\xfc\xe3\xe9m\x02\xfa\xe3o\xcc\x1f\x83\xef\xa6\xf0cnO)\xe2\x12\xa7\xc5\xee\x91\xd9]\xd3\xea\x1b\x83\x93-\t\x9b\xe4\xa7_\x0f\x8b\xdd\x89f\xf3H=\xf7wRY\x14I\xdc\xa4e\xf1\xc8<'I\xd5\x9b\x92\xf4|\x1b/\xb3\x94b$u!O\xb6\x11\xbb\x05,\xcf\xf6\x800\xe6{\xfc(\xde\xf6\xc6c\xcc\xf7\x04\x10\v\t\x8c\xf00\x1c\xb1O\x14j\xaf\x9e\x154\x01O\x8c\xac\xa8SG\xb7\xf5\x954\xd5\x95\tN^e\xe5\x891\x0c\xed\xf5\xd9\x93i<\x96\x1fB\xae\xa7\x88\xdcT\x19\xcd\x86=8\x93\x87=^\x1d\xf2=\x91\x05Ro6\xe4\x86\xd2\x10\xc0\x19u\xafY\x91\x1f\x8bp\xc8\x03\x81\xae\xf0b\xaddG\xb2\xd7\xaf\xeeb\xbd\xb0\x15y\xf2\x02" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 400 "x\x01DP[o\xda0\x18}G\xe2?\xf8\tm\xa5\x8e\xe3\\!\x15\x9a \xa3\xed\xb4vB%\x15\xda\x132\xc9G\xb0bl\xcf15\xed\xaf\x9f\xa3i\xdb\xa3\xcf\xc5\xdf9\xe7a]!\xa2\x8dj.\x9d%\x9b0\x8c\xf2|\x16\x91w&\xa1\xc6RY8(\xd5a\xd6u\x17\xa2%I\xb2h6\x0fq\x9e\xd0\xe0d\xcf\xe2K\xe7\x9a=o\x16\xd4\xe31^\xcf\xe3\xe5:_e8Z}\xcdpr\x9f%xN\xc3\x12\xaf\xb28+\xb30ZyzK\xf3tNi:\xcbR:ik\xe1\xcd\xe5\xd3n#\xdf\"\x17\xffJ\xca\xfb\x9f\xbd\x8b\x9dj\xe2Wfv\x0e=V\xd5\x86\xd0\x80\x8eG\xcb\xba\x06m\vd\xe1j\xc9p\xfa\x161\xad\x05\xaf\x99\xe5J\x92\xeb" 
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers ip] 501 "x\x014L\xcb"
```

Is this an attack attempt, if so what kind? How would I decode this? It looks like part hexadecimal

To be clear a normal line in my log file would look something like this:

```
[some timestamp] [some ip] [my servers name] 200 "GET /path/to/something.html HTTP/1.1"
```

Since the server is responding with a status `400` I'm guessing the so called attack is not working, but I'm still curious as to what is actually happening here.

Comment: This should probably be over on serverfault.

Comment: This is not about servers, this is about decoding strings to readable characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hex encoding. Supported for strings in for instance javascript. In firebug or chrome dev console you could do: console.log('ATTACK_STRING'). Replace ATTACK_STRING excluding quotes with a line from your log.

Comment: thanks, thats a pretty easy way to decode these strings, to bad it still translates to gibberish though :( I guess I'll have to assume the answer to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202901/who-can-decode-this-code) question as well.